# The IListSource does not contain any data sources.during next page is clicked in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

```
Lbl_Username.Text = FirstName + " " + LastName;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ds = objSun.FetchTravelDetails(userId);
        int datasetcount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        if (datasetcount == 0)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("request_ID");
            dt.Columns.Add("userId");
            dt.Columns.Add("");
            dt.Columns.Add("status");
            dt.Columns.Add("remark");
            dt.Columns.Add("");
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            GridView_RequisitionManagement.DataSource = dt;
            GridView_RequisitionManagement.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView_RequisitionManagement.DataSource = ds;
            GridView_RequisitionManagement.DataBind();
        }
    } 
}

protected void GridView_RequisitionManagement_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int datasetcount1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    if (datasetcount1 != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView_RequisitionManagement.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            LinkButton lnk_view = new LinkButton();
            lnk_view = GridView_RequisitionManagement.Rows[i].FindControl("LinkBtn_ViewFullDetails_GridView_LeaveManagement") as LinkButton;

            int type = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["request_Type"].ToString());
            string typeName = "";
            string requestId = GridView_RequisitionManagement.DataKeys[i][0].ToString();
            string request_userId = GridView_RequisitionManagement.DataKeys[i][1].ToString();
            switch (type)
            {
                case 2:
                    {
                        typeName = "Travel Request";
                        lnk_view.PostBackUrl = "Status_ViewDetails_TravelClaims.aspx?requestId=" + requestId;
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        typeName = "Other Claims";
                        lnk_view.PostBackUrl = "Status_ViewDetails_OtherClaims.aspx?requestId=" + requestId;
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        typeName = "Petty cash";
                        lnk_view.PostBackUrl = "Status_ViewDetails_PettyCashVoucher.aspx?requestId=" + requestId;
                        break;
                    }
                case 5:
                    {
                        typeName = "Advance";
                        lnk_view.PostBackUrl = "Status_ViewDetails_AdvanceRequisitions.aspx?requestId=" + requestId;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            GridView_RequisitionManagement.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["date"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
            GridView_RequisitionManagement.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text = typeName;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < GridView_RequisitionManagement.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            GridViewRow rows = GridView_RequisitionManagement.Rows[j];
            LinkButton lnk_grd_views = (LinkButton)rows.FindControl("LinkBtn_ViewFullDetails_GridView_LeaveManagement") as LinkButton;
            lnk_grd_views.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

protected void GridView_RequisitionManagement_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    GridView_RequisitionManagement.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView_RequisitionManagement.DataSource = ds;
    GridView_RequisitionManagement.DataBind();

}
```

Hi guys, I need some help here. I'm using the above code to display the details
in the `GridView`. The `DataTable` and `DataSet` are used to populate the `GridView`. Now I want to do paging in the `GridView`, but when the next page is clicked it shows the following error:

> The IListSource does not contain any data sources

and the next page in the grid shows empty.

Please assist me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you are only setting the DataSet 'ds' if it isn't a postback. So when the PageIndexChanging event is run ds is not going to be set to a dataset.

Try moving

```
ds = objSun.FetchTravelDetails(userId);
```

Above the `if(!IsPostback)` line.

Comment: thanks DaveParsons your advice really worked and now the next page is showing with the data. thanks one more time yaar. this issue being killing me for weeks.